# logstash configuration for hourly input files

Tags: logstash-configuration

I have a system that generates log files every hour, for eg. log_20160522_2200.log, log_20160522_2300.log, log_20160523_0000.log.

As of now I am scheduling logstash execution every hour to process new files.

How can I specify the input filter so that I do not have to reschedule logstash via cron for every hour.

As is evident I am new to logstash, so kindly bear. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If the logs are in the same folder you can refer to them as "log_*.log". You will need to use the [input filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html) for this with the [file option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html).

Example:

```
input {
      file { 
            path => "log_*.log"
      }
 }
```

This will check for new lines at the end of the file by default. If you want to start reading from the beginning of the file. You need to use the [option start_position](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-start_position).

Example:

```
 input { 
       file { 
             path => "log_*.log" 
             start_position => "beginning"
       } 
 }
```